# SharePoint 2013 / Data Scrubbing

Tags: content-database, database, delete, data, recycle-bin

After you delete an item or document from a list or library, and then the recycle bin and secondary recycle bin, does the data remain in the database for a certain amount of time? .. or forever unless you do something else to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

The recycle bin automatic deletion is set for 30 days from the date of deletion.

If an item is deleted from the site recycle bin it go s to the site collection recycle bin.

If you remove a file from site recycle bin say after 15 days it will only be available in the site collection recycle bin for a further 15 days.

You can configure the number of days settings via central administration.

Comment: but does the data remain in the database or anywhere hidden after it leaves the secondary recycle bin?

Comment: As per my understanding the data will be lost and can't be recovered once the date expires.